# how I can upload any file or image to Google cloud Storage from Android

Tags: android, upload, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload file from Android device to Google Cloud Storage. For that I have create project in Google cloud using JSON API and create bucket related to that. Then Create Service Account key that is p12 file.

But then stuck how to code it in Android Programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String uploadFile(RichMedia media) {
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapUtils.getBitmap(media.getLocalUrl());
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(GCS_ROOT + media.getLocalUrl() + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis());
if(media.getType() == RichMedia.RichMediaType.PICTURE) {
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
} else {
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
}
post.setHeader("Authorization", "AIzaSyCzdmCMwiMzl6LD7R2obF0xSgnnx5rEfeI");
//post.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(bitmap.getByteCount()));
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

try {
    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(new Gson().toJson(byteArray).toString()));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    String eachLine = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while ((eachLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(eachLine);
    }
    L.d("response = " + builder.toString());
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
    String name = object.getString("name");
    return  name;
} catch (IOException e) {
    L.print(e);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    L.print(e);
}
return null;
```

}

you can leran from this code